# Salesforce SOAP Login() returning NULL value in Session Id

Tags: apex, integration, webservices, soap

I have imported the partner WSDL and I am getting NULL value in ServerURL/SessionId after login() call.

```
partnerSoapSforceCom p = new partnerSoapSforceCom();
partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult e = new partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult();
String uname = 'USERNAME';
String pwd = 'PWD+TOKEN';
System.debug('The result of the login call is => '+e);
System.debug('ServerURL = '+e.serverURL);
System.debug('Session Id = '+e.SessionId);
System.debug('Get Session Id = '+e.getSessionId());
```

**Debug shows**

```
16:12:27:015 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|The result of the login call is => LoginResult:[apex_schema_type_info=(urn:partner.soap.sforce.com, true, false), field_order_type_info=(metadataServerUrl, passwordExpired, sandbox, serverUrl, sessionId, userId, userInfo), metadataServerUrl=null, metadataServerUrl_type_info=(metadataServerUrl, urn:partner.soap.sforce.com, null, 1, 1, true), passwordExpired=null, passwordExpired_type_info=(passwordExpired, urn:partner.soap.sforce.com, null, 1, 1, false), sandbox=null, sandbox_type_info=(sandbox, urn:partner.soap.sforce.com, null, 1, 1, false), serverUrl=null, serverUrl_type_info=(serverUrl, urn:partner.soap.sforce.com, null, 1, 1, true), sessionId=null, sessionId_type_info=(sessionId, urn:partner.soap.sforce.com, null, 1, 1, true), userId=null, userId_type_info=(userId, urn:partner.soap.sforce.com, null, 1, 1, true), userInfo=null, userInfo_type_info=(userInfo, urn:partner.soap.sforce.com, null, 0, 1, false)]
```

[image]

Can someone let know what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating new object of partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult and printing it. As it does not contains any data its showing null.

Try to call login method store the response in partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult object and then print the result like:

```
partnerSoapSforceCom.soap obj = new partnerSoapSforceCom.soap();
partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult e = obj.login('xxxxx@xxxx.com','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

System.debug(e);
```

You will see some values

Comment: How silly of me..tx